# Can I JOIN a table based on an SQL if-statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables being used for this problem: songs, blacklist, and whitelist. The songs table has a column named "accessType" which stores one of these four values: public, private, blacklist, whitelist. I'm trying to fetch a list of all the songs a user may access. The first condition is that songs.accessType != private. Here comes the tricky part: if songs.accessType = blacklist, I need to check that the user's ID is not within the blacklist table. Similarly, if songs.accessType = whitelist, I need to check that the user's ID is within the whitelist table. It seems to me like I need to JOIN the blacklist and/or whitelist table under certain conditions, but I have no idea if this is possible, or even the right approach. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Here's an explanation of my table schema:

> **songs**: id, name, acessType, userID
>
> **blacklist**: songID, userID
>
> **whitelist**: songID, userID

**Edit**
Here's a breakdown of the foreign keys:
songs.id -> blacklist.songID
songs.id -> whitelist.songID
songs.userID -> blacklist.userID
songs.userID -> whitelist.userID

Ravish's answer is working, but I'm interested to see why people are saying it's not efficient as possible.

Also, what is the significance of the @ symbol before userID? I replaced @userID with ? and I am binding parameters to the query.

@Workshop Alex - private songs should not be included at all.

Comment: Please don't suggest a better database structure! This Q is far too interesting for such a suggestion! :-)

Comment: could you please explain the foreign key relations between your tables? it’s important to know if we want to give you a good answer with the correct joins

Comment: How about the private songs of the user himself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM SONGS s
WHERE
   accesstype='public'
   OR (accesstype='whitelist' 
      AND EXISTS (SELECT null FROM WHITELIST wl WHERE 
          wl.songid = s.id AND wl.userid=s.userid))
   OR (accesstype='blacklist' 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM BLACKLIST bl WHERE 
          bl.songid = s.id AND bl.userid= s.userid))
```

If accesstype=private, it won't slip through, there's no need for an additional clause.

I chose using correlated subqueries because they are, in this case, more readable than filtered left joins. Perhaps MySQL is a tiny bit less efficient at them, but one should not make decisions about design based on minor temporary limitations of the query optimizer, unless the performance difference is absolutely critical. Perhaps the next version of MySQL will be even faster with this than a left join.

Comment: Shouldn't the blacklist portion be checking that the user is **not** on the blacklist?

Comment: Why "EXISTS" and not "id IN (SELECT..."?

Comment: Btw, this query doesn't select the songs for a single user but creates a list of all songs for all users! You still need another select within this Q to select the songs for a single user. So I don't understand how this would provide the required result...

Comment: @Workshop Alex, please go back and read the OP *carefully*. I think you have the wrong idea about what the use case is, and that is coloring your view of the solution. BTW, this isn't Slashdot, so please try to improve the combative tone that seems to permeate all of your comments.

Comment: »BTW, this isn't Slashdot, …« :D

Comment: @richardtallent, when someone answers "Google and find out" then I take offense to such a useless answer! Such answers are not acceptable and if it was not a comment, it would have been downvoted to oblivion.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM
    songs s
LEFT JOIN
    whitelist wl ON s.songid = wl.songid AND wl.userid = @userid
LEFT JOIN
    blacklist bl ON s.songid = bl.songid AND bl.userid = @userid
WHERE
    s.userid = @userid
AND
    s.accessType != 'private'
AND
    (
        s.accessType = 'public'
        OR
        (s.accessType = 'whitelist' AND wl.songid IS NOT NULL)
        OR
        (s.accessType = 'blacklist' AND bl.songid IS NULL)      
    )
```

Comment: Think about what a JOIN is, and how bad it could be for an optimizer to filter out NULLs from a LEFT JOIN...

Comment: It's not a good approach to left join and filtering out the results

Comment: @rexem: using keys it’s definitely faster than any `IN` or `EXISTS` query

Comment: @knittl: According to Quassnoi, LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is at best ~3% faster than NOT EXISTS while being less readable.

Comment: Why the left joins? You don't need them!

Comment: @Alex: Why do you feel the need to comment on something you know nothing about?

Comment: Rexem, I don't think a left join is any less readable than a left join and if it is faster even by 3% that can make a big difference if the query is run frequently.

Comment: @rexem: always depends on the data, i.e. many rows in one table, but not on the other, duplicate keys, etc.

Comment: @HLGEM: LEFT JOIN/IS NULL AKA ANTI-JOIN is a hack because it's less readable; MySQL is the only that I'm aware to be slightly optimized for this (likely due to optimizer bug).

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * 
    FROM Songs s 
    WHERE (s.AccessType='BlackList' AND @UserId 
            Not in(SELECT UserId From BlackList WHERE SongId=s.Id)) 
        OR (s.AccessType='WhiteList' AND @UserId  
            in(SELECT UserId From WhiteList WHERE SongId=s.Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion about this question! A few answers assume you have selected a userID somewhere and want to select all songs for this specific user. Others have assumed that you just wanted a list of all users where (userID, songID) is in the whitelist but not in the blacklist. As a result, there are two possible answers possible to this Q!

So, it could be read as two different questions:
Question 1: Given a specific user, which non-private songs can he access that are public, whitelisted or not blacklisted?
Question 2: Which non-private songs from which users are whitelisted or public or not blacklisted?

Both Q's have been answered. Question 2 was answered by [richardtallent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16306/richardtallent) and the other by me. In Q2, using EXISTS is the best option simply because the sub-select is always returning a single result and EXISTS will just translate to true or false, which is more optimized.
In Q1, the use of IN is better because you need to check for multiple values in the same subset. The parser will execute the sub-selection once and store the resultset, instead of executing this for every row. Thus, in this case the use of IN is better.

I hope this will clear up some of the confusion that has occurred in this Q. Technically speaking, the outcome of the answer could be considered subjective! The confusion arises from the line *"I'm trying to fetch a list of all the songs **a user** may access."*. This made me and several others think that you've already selected a single user and needed to collect his songs.

Answer (score -1):

You try joining BOTH tables with two conditions for each (userID and accessType).

Answer (score -1):

use string comparison in your `ON` clause and intelligently join with your black and whitelist

```
    SELECT `s`.*
      FROM `songs` `s`
INNER JOIN `whitelist` `w`
        ON `s`.`id` = `w`.`songID`
       AND `s`.`userID` = `w`.`userID`
       AND `s`.`accessType` = 'whitelist';
 LEFT JOIN `blacklist` `b`
        ON `s`.`id` = `b`.`songID`
       AND `s`.`userID` = `b`.`userID`
       AND `s`.`accessType` = 'blacklist'
     WHERE `b`.`songID` IS NULL
       AND `s`.`accessType` <> 'private'
       AND `s`.`userID` = $youruserid;
```

this will select all songs for a given `userid` which are public, inner joined with `whitelist` (so you only get songs on the whitelist).

the left join with `blacklists` then selects only rows which don’t have a blacklist entry

ps. i’m not exactly sure what your foreign key relations are, maybe you could elaborate that a little?

Comment: could the people downvoting please explain why they are doing this? if my answer is wrong i sure want to know why so i don’t make the same mistake in the future

Comment: It's too complex! You don't need a join since you're selecting from a single table. The Q is wrong in assuming you need a join! As a result, everyone seems to make the solution far more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @Alex: A join is too complex?!

Comment: joins are fast, easy and concise. `NOT EXISTS` gets called for every row in the first select, joins can be often faster

Comment: Not complex, just not required in this case!

Comment: @Alex: Always nice to see you backpedal. Is it too complex or isn't it?  Since when does selecting from a single table indicate the use of IN vs JOIN?

Comment: complexity is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: anyway, the question was »can i **JOIN** a table based on an SQL if-statement« and i gave him a join